# Restricting read/write to firestore based on android package name

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase project which contains 3 different android applications. These 3 applications utilize the same data stored under Cloud Firestore. My problem is that some of the data is particular to a single app only while some documents contain data which is supposed to be read by two of the three apps. I need to write Firestore security rules to implement this.

Is it possible to restrict read/writes to a particular document based on the android package name without having to explicitly send data regarding the app-id in each request?

Is there anything else which can be used instead of the package name to uniquely identify the applications while adding firestore security rules?

So far I have been trying to restrict read and writes based on the kind of authentication used by the apps as one app uses only phone auth while the other uses both email and phone linked together. So if the email is missing but the phone is present, I know it's from the first app. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible exactly as you're describing.  Security rules don't have any way of determining or limiting the origin of access.  They just limit *who* can read and write what data, as determined by Firebase Authentication.

You can use the authentication provider of the signed-in user via [`request.auth.firebase.sign_in_provider`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth), or any of the other per-user properties shown in the linked documentation.  You can also use [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) in `request.auth.token` to tag users with some privilege that allows their access to some data, which must be set using the Firebase Admin SDK on your backend.